# Nested SSRS IIF should work (I think) but doesn't

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I believe this code should work but I keep getting #Error

```
=IIF(Fields!MonthMiddleDates8.Value <> "", "TRUE",
     IIF(Fields!MonthMiddleDates9.Value <> "", "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Comment: Are you using this where a **Boolean** result is expected? If so, don't use quotes around the true or false

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  '<> "" ' use  'is nothing'.  Works great now!